# Can anybody explain the contrapositive

Tags: math, logic, discrete-mathematics, truthtable

I'm trying to construct a contrapositive for the following statement: **If A is 0 or B is 0, then A*B is 0.**

Here is my attempt: **If A*B is not 0, then A is not 0 or B is not 0.**

The original statement is true, but the contrapositive is false since both A **and** B must be non-zero in order for A*B to be non-zero... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And how come it's tagged C++?

Comment: C++ has logic... and people that like C++ often like challenging questions (I guess this was not very challenging :)).

Comment: Note that the contrapositive of a true statement is always true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

The contrapositive of "If P then Q" is "If not Q, then not P".

So the contrapositive of "If A is 0 or B is 0, then A`*`B is 0" is "If A`*`B is not 0, then not(A is 0 or B is 0)".

And "not(A is 0 or B is 0)" is "A is not 0 **and** B is not 0", so the contrapositive should be "If A`*`B is not 0, then A is not 0 and B is not 0". Just what you expect :-)

Answer (score 2):

you need to change the main "or" into an and. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

so: If A*B is not 0, then A is not 0 and B is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've done something wrong.  NOT(A or B) = NOT(A) *and* NOT(B).  You neglected to change 'or' to 'and' when distributing the 'not'. ([De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))